# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a basic problem with TypeScript. I have an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I have model `EmailModel`:

```
export class EmailModel {

    public name: String;
    public lastname: String;
    public address: String;
    public company: String;
    public zipcode: number;
    public city: String;
    public phonenumber: number;
    public email: String;
    public product: Array<ProductModelOrder>=[];

    constructor(name: String, lastname: String, address: String, company: String, zipcode: number, city: String, phonenumber: number, email: String,product: Array<ProductModelOrder>=[]) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.address = address;
        this.company = company;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
        this.city = city;
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
        this.email = email;
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

And my `product` array look like this:

```
export class ProductModelOrder {
    public name: String;
    public number: number;
    public pricePerProduct:number;
    public price:number;
}
```

This is my `productOrder =< ProductModelOrder>{};` and  `emailModel = <EmailModel>{};` and I want productOrder to emailModel like this:

```
for (let prod of this.productCarts){
      this.productOrder.name = prod.product_name;
      this.productOrder.number = prod.numberOfProduct;
      this.productOrder.pricePerProduct = prod.product_price;  
      this.productOrder.price = this.priceForAllProducts; 
      this.emailModel.product.push(this.productOrder);
    }
```

And I have error.

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned your `emailModel = <EmailModel>{};` so `product` property is `undefined` then you are `this.emailModel.product.push(this.productOrder);` which cause the error

so instead you need to do `emailModel = new EmailModel(...params here);`

also you can do this

```
export class EmailModel {

    public name: String;
    public lastname: String;
    public address: String;
    public company: String;
    public zipcode: number;
    public city: String;
    public phonenumber: number;
    public email: String;
    public product: Array<ProductModelOrder>=[];

    constructor(params: EmailModel) {
       Object.assign(this, params);
    }
}
```

then

```
emailModel = new EmailModel({...params here});
```

### Simple example

```
export class Person {
   name: string;
   phones: Array<string>;
   age?:number; //optional

   constrcutor(params: Person) {
     Object.assign(this, params);
   }
}

const p = new Person({name: 'Reza', phones: ['6583992']})
```